Terminal server 2022 - Edge / Chrome out of memory and DWM crash
recently my users have been encountering an issue on a Windows Terminal Server 2022. Chrome and Edge display a message: "out of memory." In the Event Viewer, we have a crash of Chrome (Application Hang) and a crash of DWM (process ism.dll).
Actions I've already taken:
Increased RAM (when it crashed, only 60% of the ram was consumed)
Clear the various caches
Deactivate hardware acceleration
The problem still persists
Thanks in advance
